# How to get last 30 min reocrds for last 30 days transactions in SQL Server -PIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am able to get the last 30 days of transactions hourly wise, however, would like to get the records for every 15 min. Below is the code what I am using.

Seeking help on below :

1. How to make this report every 15 min?

   How to get the sum and average of transactions in the attached sample (Ex: I would like to get a daily average of transactions)
2. How to get an average transaction on an hourly basis. (Ex: at 10 AM what is the average transactions on all days).

[image: sample]

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         CAST(DateAdded AS DATE) [Date],
         DATEPART(hour,DateAdded) [Hour],
         COUNT(1) [number of Transactions]
     FROM 
         [tablename] 
     WHERE 
         Text LIKE '%ABC%')
GROUP BY 
    CAST(DateAdded AS DATE), DATEPART(hour,DateAdded)) AS StartTime
PIVOT
    (SUM([number of Transactions])
          FOR [Hour] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
    ) AS DatePivot 
ORDER BY 
    Date
```

Comment: I think you need to create a job https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-transact-sql-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: DATEPART is your answer here. USE minute instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 along with mod 15 (%)  = 0  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15